# Whats the Difference between Convert.ToDateTime(value) and (DateTime)value

Tags: c#, datetime

Out of curiosity I was wondering what the difference was between

```
Convert.ToDateTime(value)
```

and

```
(DateTime)value
```

although the first line in my opinion has better readability I don't understand why there needs to be static method to carry out the conversion

Comment: What is the type of `value`?

Comment: Did you mean to compare `Convert.ToDateTime` and `DateTime.Parse`?  Because casting is completely different from converting or parsing.

Comment: @SonerGönül in this case value would have to be of type `object` to satisfy the two lines

Comment: I *assume* `value` is an object, `Convert.ToDateTime` try to parse your `value` based [standard date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture` settings. It uses `DateTime.Parse` method explicitly. `(DateTime)value` is just a [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). That means if your `value` object is not a `DateTime`, that will throw exception. If it is an _alredy_ `DateTime`, casting will be succeed.